# Two physical servers on one IP behind one router

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, port-forwarding

I asked this question on StackOverflow and was directed here to ServerFault. I searched the forums here and find 3 or so inquiries that are very similar but not quite the same (or maybe I just don't understand them).

I have two physical servers (both Mac Minis with Ubuntu LAMP installs) that I want to make accessible through one IP (one router). Each of the servers will be accessed via a unique domain that is hosted elsewhere but has its a record pointing to my IP. (e.g. site1.com & site2.com both point to the same IP and behind the router of that IP is two Ubuntu servers)

I've hosted one of these for a long time with no issue and am now attempting to add another. I was hoping that I could go this easy (and lazy) route:

Name each Apache server (with the domain that will be forwarded to it) 
Allow access to one via "Local server" setting on my router (Planex MKZ-04G)
Designate the other as a DMZ host

but that is going to mean they are both using port 80....and it won't work...or will it?

So, my next thought is, can I have Apache on one of the machines both serve a site and act as a reverse proxy...?

Does all that make sense...?

Any help provided will be much appreciated.

Regards

Jason

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by having two servers?

Comment: Michael - Funny :-) Yes, the Mac Mini with Ubuntu works quite nicely and I would like to keep it that way by using two different machines as opposed to adding a virtual host to one.

Comment: What's wrong with virtual hosting, then? Adding a second box would just add complexity in this scenario with no apparent benefit.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, you are recommending hosting both sites on one machine? I want to avoid that so as to allow each the resources available on the machine (RAM, processor, drive space). Or, are you recommending reverse proxy on one...?

Comment: You never said anything about needing more resources, even though I asked! And if you really do need more resources, you probably shouldn't be using Mac Minis at all...

Comment: You don't really seem motivated to help :-( I don't need more...I need to not use more on the machines I have. And, when did you ask? You only made a snide comment.

Comment: I have been trying to help you clarify your situation, but you don't seem interested in being helped. If you change your mind please feel free to edit your question.

Comment: Interesting...trying to help...? Where? Sarcasm and avoidance of my initial inquiry....first time I've experienced this kind of treatment here.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "this kind of treatment" as you have never been here before, and as far as I can tell you have been treated fairly. The problem is with your question itself: Despite several attempts to get you to clarify and improve it, I'm pretty well convinced at this point that you were misdirected and that your question does not belong here at all. [sf] is meant for questions about professional IT, and it appears that what you're doing - and what you propose to do - have little or no relation to this.

Comment: Michael - I am not sure why you think my question is not related to "professional IT" but...  I guess I was misdirected.  Correct, though, I have not been here before. I have been on Stackoverflow and was always treated in a professional manner there. Your first response included the snide comment about a Mac Mini not being a server. Your second response reverted to something I'd already said I didn't want to do. Your third response refers to an inquiry that was never made (you did not ask about resources) and then in your fourth response you state that you were trying to clarify...no. :-(

Comment: A simple reply like the helpful one provided by FiZi would have been more than sufficient.

Comment: P.S. I will not go back and edit my comments ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With one public IP you won't be able to host both web sites on port 80 using two physically separate servers. You'll have to run one on 80 and another on 8080 which is an annoyance.

You could instead setup a proxy on one of the physical servers. The downside is you'll have a single point of failure (the server running the proxy) and it adds complexity. You'll also likely need to setup internal DNS servers or at least goof with the hosts files on your servers.

If your using Apache check out mod_proxy.

I see your worried about load. You might want to consider using one server as your web server and use the other as your database server.

Comment: FiZi thank you very much for your informative response. It is helpful and will get me moving in the correct direction.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't add an answer here as my original question was closed for very dubious reasons. At any rate, after days of trial and error I managed to accomplish what I wanted. It may not be ideal but I wanted to learn and accomplish something.. In the end 2 virtual hosts with the same IP (one using ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse pointing to an external server & the other pointing to the local server) accomplished what I wanted. :-) We'll see how it performs...and, for the record....this is for university use (business..I guess not but more than just fun hobby work) :-)